# How to set scroll button and middle click emulation on a trackball in 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, mouse, wayland, xorg.conf

I had middle click emulation and scroll on my Logitech TrackMan Marble using xorg.conf settings on my 20.04, but when I upgraded to 22.04 it stopped working, I tried various changes in xorg.conf (some of them broke my X completely) and nothing worked, what do I do?

Answer (score 2):

After searching, I found out that wayland is changing the way things work on 22.04, and I need to change it via gsettings, I explored the various settings and what worked for me was this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.trackball scroll-wheel-emulation-button 8 # uses the second button from the left)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.trackball middle-click-emulation true
```

If you use a mouse, change the trackball to mouse in the path.